# How can I add a break point in VSCode to a dart file from an imported package?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

When an exception is thrown from within a dart file from an imported package VSCode will automatically open that source file to show where the exception was thrown. Once this file is open and attached to the debugger I appear to be able to add break points anywhere inside. This makes me believe it should be possible to add other files manually. I would like to open and attach other dart files to the debugger that I know are being referenced and add break points.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to enable one or two `Dart Code` settings:

Add to your user settings the following:

```
"dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries": true,
"dart.debugSdkLibraries": true,
```

The first will allow debugging of pub packages; while the second will allow debugging of Flutter sdk.

Comment: `"dart.debugExternalLibraries"` doesn't exist, and ["dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries"](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartdebugexternalpackagelibraries) is needed now.